# How to limit ng-deep class for ng bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I want to limit the ng-deep class to only a certain component?
I have class

```
::ng-deep .modal-dialog {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1100px !important;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

.modal-dialog is ng bootstrap class for modal. modal-dialog class is not my class i only run over modal class.
This is work good but when I open another modal which not need max-width and display the .modal-dialog class is inherited in that component in which it should not be active.

I understand that it would be okay if I could wrap in a class, for example

```
.any-class { 

    ::ng-deep .modal-dialog {
      display: flex;
      max-width: 1100px !important;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}
```

but .modal-dialog is above all classes

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **ng-bootstrap**, there are 2 options for this when opening the dialog.

First, you can use `windowClass` to add a class to the window that opens the modal.

```
    this.modalService
      .open(content, {
        ariaLabelledBy: "modal-basic-title",
        windowClass: "myDialog"
      })
```

Second, you can use the `container` option to pass in the selector of the div that you want the modal to open within.

Add to html in your component

```
<div id="myModal"></div>
```

Then with the modal service.

```
 this.modalService
  .open(content, {
    ariaLabelledBy: "modal-basic-title",
    container: "#myModal"
  })
```

This will cause the dialog to be opened from within your component tree.

More modal options can be found here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api#NgbModalOptions

For **ngx-bootstrap**:

Use the `class` or `id` option to add a specific selector to your modal, use that to target for max-width

```
openModalWithClass(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(
      template,
      Object.assign({}, { class: 'myDialog' })
    );
  }
```

Ref: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-custom-css-class

Comment: i am using ngx bootstrap